# Remove Ordered/Unordered Bullets while copy pasting in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html.textbox

While copy pasting a text from MS Word to html textbox, the bullet appends in the text box. How to remove it using Jquery/Javascript ?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i copied a text in a list from a word doc, and paste it in the html textbox. I used the below code to allow only alphanumeric while pasting a value in text box. but the above bullets is represented as "o" character. so it couldnt be restricted. 



$("#CustomerId").on("paste", function (e) {
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    $("#CustomerId").val(pastedData.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, ""));
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: I updated my answer to also check for 'o' followed by spaces

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to remove the unwanted characters from a textbox. One way is to use regualr expression to filter out any non-alphanumberic characters from that value field and put the filtered value back into the textbox, replacing/overwriting the old value.

```js
$('#my_textbox').keyup(function() {
  //this code will be triggered after each keystroke inside the textbox
  // alternatively, you may want to only trigger it after blur/change/etc

  var cleaned = $(this).val().replace(/^\s*[o\W]\s+/g, '');
  //removes any letter 'o' followed by spaces
  //removes any non-alphanumeric followed by spaces

  $(this).val(cleaned);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Paste something here with a bullet point</h3>
<input type="text" id="my_textbox">
```